# Query by array of ObjectIds

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an array of `ObjectID`s, representing `_id` values for documents in a collection:

```
ObjectID[] documentsAffected
```

How can I prepare a query to return all the documents that are referenced in this array?

I have looked at the following but it only works with individual values, not arrays:

```
Query.EQ("_id", documentsAffected)
```

I don't want to write a for loop and have to return one document at a time either, because I then need to update these documents in the same way and this seems inefficient when I could update them all in one statement after retrieving them all.

Is there a way to effectively do this? If not, is there another way to return all documents based on some list of items that reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `In` instead of `EQ`:

```
Query.In("_id", documentsAffected);
```

Or better off, using the typed options:

```
Query<Document>.In(doc => doc.Id, documentsAffected);
```

This will create a query using the `$in` operator:

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array

From [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the second option you specified.